# Firebase Storage Sync api

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to develop an app whereby I want to exchange files (video, images) within the cloud storage(firebase) and client(android app).

I wanted to know if there is any sync API in firebase which keeps track of any updates i.e any changes being performed in the firebase storage and replicating the same to the client (and vice-versa if possible).

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Go to the page of [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) and read what the header says:

> **Store and sync data in real time**

Furthermore:

> The Firebase Realtime Database is a cloud-hosted NoSQL database that
> lets you store and **sync** data between your users in real-time.

What `Realtime` means is this:

> Instead of typical HTTP requests, the Firebase Realtime Database uses
> data synchronization—every time data changes, any connected device
> receives that update within milliseconds. Provide collaborative and
> immersive experiences without thinking about networking code.

**So just add Realtime Database Dependency and you are set. This itself will serve the purpose of `Sync API` you need.**

Comment: Hey @Novo are you able to find any API to automatically sync the local storage with online storage(Like new file created, updated, deleted). Give me a guide